# scandir directory difference from WAMP to shared linux server

Tags: php

I had a script that ran fine on a local WAMP server that I'm trying to move over to a shared linux server on Bluehost.  The problem seems to be with the directory.  In windows, I was able to just go from the drive root.

```
$dir = 'C:/inetpub/wwwroot/images/';
```

On my linux server, I've tried going from the host root, but I'm not familiar with the syntax

```
$dir = '//home3/udmdevco/public_html/images/';
```

How do I traverse the directory from the host root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 'home3' is truly a root directory, then just one slash at the beginning should do it:

```
$dir = '/home3/udmdevco/public_html/images/';
```

Comment: It's not site root, but it is my host root.  It works for my .sql scripts but not for these images for some reason.

Comment: Well the syntax on linux is definitely a single forward slash at the beginning of a root path. If you're having problems, then there's something else going on (permissions on the folder? wrong path?)